# D'ont share ngrxStore between custom elements

Tags: angular, ngrx, web-component

I have an Angular custom element (exported as webcomponent) that dispatches some action to a search state, to perform a search. The search state action handling is done in an angular library inside of my project.
The goal of the webcomponent is to display search result, accordingly to the input filter that it declares.

If I add 2 instances of this custom element with 2 differents search parameters, they will display the same result as they share the same state.

Custom element Result.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ResultComponent],
  imports: [
    LibSearchModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({}),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(),
  ],
})
export class ResultModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const resultCpt = createCustomElement(ResultComponent, {
      injector: this.injector,
    })
    customElements.define('search-result', resultCpt)
  }
}
```

ResultComponent.ts

```js
  @Input() filter
  constructor(private store: Store<SearchState>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(
      new SetSearch({ filters: { any: this.filter } })
    )
  }
```

index.html

```html
    <search-result
      filter="river"
    ></search-result>

    <search-result
      filter="forest"
    ></search-result>
```

I would like that each WC has it's own state, so each one perform the correct search and display the correct results.
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the injector. Try specifying an injector that is built at each instance, probably what you defined in the code is the same for both instances of the component.